# CSS - Border where only half of a border is visible

Tags: html, css

I am confused as to have to make it work in CSS only to have a div where the border would be only visible on half it's width.

The border style is a simple `1px solid #000;`

However, I want the top of the `div`'s border to not be visible everywhere (on 100% on the `div`'s width),
rather only on the first 50% of the `div`'s width.

I haven't been able to get an example of this anywhere, and it needs to be in percentages, so the usual bag of tricks (image over the second half,...).

Comment: Code please! Tough to answer questions without it.

Comment: I'd say this is near impossible to achieve only with css and without markup changes or using tricks specific to the css/html on your site.

Comment: @Drewdin and Casey what do you need code for? The question is simple: it's about a div and a border.

Comment: My bad guys, I'm not asking for anything specific, just if it's even possible to accomplish this using only CSS.

The code would look something like this:

HTML:
<div id="holder"></div>

CSS:
#holder {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

Comment: you need border gradient for this check out this links to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Comment: @MrLister providing code shows effort and creates a framework so that everyone is on the same page.

Comment: I cannot see what code he could provide besides `1px solid #000;`.

Answer (score 40):

You can use CSS gradient border

[image: half of border]

```css
.half-a-border-on-top {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 100% 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="half-a-border-on-top">Hello world!</span>
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant answer. A more general answer might use transparent instead of white.

Comment: no use of position absolute, this is perfect answer

Comment: Best answer, very precise. It worked for me.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for this elegant and simple solution :)

Comment: what about if you need the other sides and you just want only half of the top border to appear?

Answer (score 35):

If you do not want to mess with the HTML at all, you can do it with an empty pseudoelement, using CSS only. You still need to know the background color, of course (assuming white here):

```
<span class="half-a-border-on-top">Hello world!</span>

<style>
.half-a-border-on-top {
  border-top:1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.half-a-border-on-top:after {
  padding:0;margin:0;display:block;/* probably not really needed? */
  content: "";
  width:50%;
  height:1.1px;/* slight higher to work around rounding errors(?) on some zoom levels in some browsers. */
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:-1px;
}
</style>
```

**Result:**

[image: Half of a top border visible above the text "Hello world"]

**Snippet**

```css
    .half-a-border-on-top {
      border-top:1px solid black;
      position: relative;
    }
    .half-a-border-on-top:after {
      padding:0;margin:0;display:block;/* probably not really needed? */
      content: "";
      width:50%;
      height:1.1px;
      background-color:white;
      position: absolute;
      right:0;
      top:-1px;
    }
```

```html
    <span class="half-a-border-on-top">Hello world!</span>
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/vL1qojj8/

Edit 2023: Now that even Safari seems to fully and properly support `linear-gradient`, the answer by [红了樱桃绿了吧唧](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9288031/%e7%ba%a2%e4%ba%86%e6%a8%b1%e6%a1%83%e7%bb%bf%e4%ba%86%e5%90%a7%e5%94%a7) is probably more elegant, and will work without knowing the background color.

Answer (score 31):

Would this work:

```css
#holder {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        position:relative;
        margin:10px;
} 
#mask {
        position: absolute;
        top:-1px;
        left:1px;
        width:50%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
        <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is showing only the second half instead of hidding it, but you get the idea, just change the position.

Comment: So simple and beautiful! Well done. Great to use for nav button underline styling!

Comment: What if you wanted a transparent background behind it?

Comment: You're an MVP, what a champ!

Answer (score 1):

let show you how i edit the code of leo, to put a half border at left in center.

try this:

html code

`<div class="half-a-border-on-left">Hello world!</div>`

css code

```
   <style>
.half-a-border-on-left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.half-a-border-on-left:after {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  left:-1px;
  top: -10px;
}
.half-a-border-on-left:before {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
</style>
```

Those are code i use to put a half border  thank you leo,