# Border not full height of css element

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to make the border of an element not span the full length of the element. I've seen some suggestions to use line-height though that doesn't seem to work for me (at least not with the `<ul>` tag which is what I'm using).

A popular example of someone doing this would be the search at http://android.com which has this sort of effect though I can't find anything relating to it in the css.

Ex:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTn5i.png]

Comment: What line are you referring to in your image? And what have you tried? Show some code. Seems to be a `div` with `height:5px; width:1px; background:#ccc;`

Comment: line height would dictate the height, not the length. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The one on the left of the search input. The bottom one is a border-bottom style element but I can't find anything that produces that border on the left, hence why there's no code.

Comment: I would use a <table> structure and let the bottom row with a small height, have boarder bottom and border left for the cell/cells.

Comment: Here's is one of many examples using 2 divs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804417/css-border-where-only-half-of-a-border-is-visible

Comment: @Vector I was looking for a way without having to resort to using a second div.

Comment: @IgnianSoft If your example is not relevant, since they're basically using two elements to achieve this effect, then you should remove it from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Android are using two elements to achieve this effect, if they can't do it with one element, i doubt we could.

Comment: According to the CSS specification, borders enclose the entire element to which they are applied.  Therefore, the only way to get this type of an effect is to either use a combination of a wrapper element with absolute positioning.  Alternatively, you could apply a carefully constructed background image of the border shape.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like this... It's not completely cross browser due to pseudo-elements and contenteditable, but it's a different solution -- and it works.

**HTML**

```
<!--// can't use pseudo elements on input, so let's make a div contenteditable //-->
<div class="foo" contenteditable></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;    
}

.foo:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 150px;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bada55;
}
.foo:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    width: 1px;
    background: #bada55;
}

.foo:focus {
    outline: solid transparent;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/gvMqU/)**

Comment: Why are you using a `:before` and an `:after`? Just use one short element with `border-bottom` and `border-left`.

Comment: @user1618143 The OP wants a CSS-only solution.

Comment: This worked perfectly though I don't need all the pseudo elements :)

Comment: @Boaz I stated that my question was relating to achieving this with <ul> elements. Sorry for the confusion with my example being an <input> element.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it could have been simpler without the pseudo elements... For some reason it just looked *off* to me without them, but if it works for you... I'm glad :)

Comment: Uh, since when are `border-bottom` and `border-left` not pure CSS? I mean, you'd still need a `:before` or an `:after`, but not both.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another option for the mix. `box-shadow` is fast becoming one of my favourite new CSS features...

### No extra markup, nothing but CSS (and no pseudo-elements)...

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/npsMx/2/

### HTML

```
<input type="text" class="search" />
```

### CSS

```
.search {
    border: 0px solid blue;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 4px 0px -4px blue;
       -moz-box-shadow: -5px 4px 0px -4px blue;
            box-shadow: -5px 4px 0px -4px blue;
}
```

We force the `box-shadow` on to just the left hand side. Setting it to `-5px` sets the width on the left to just that... The `-4px` later effectively shuffles is back across the way leaving just one pixel visible (i.e. equal to our `border-bottom-width`.

Hard to explain but easy to see if you just play with the values!

Comment: What an idea! Nicely done. I love seeing box shadows used and abused :P [I do it often](http://codepen.io/brbcoding/2).

Comment: Updated answer for completeness (`-webkit` and `-moz` variants added).

Comment: This has the notable disadvantage that you can't adjust the height of the left tick, it will always be the height of the input element

Comment: I had a different situation of partial border and I used this technique successfully.

Comment: Great tool for helping creating the box shadow element visually
https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the markup in your example:

```
<div class="search" id="search-container">
    <div class="search-inner">
        <div id="search-btn"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <form action="/search/" id="search" name="search">
            <input id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search" speech="" type="text" x-webkit-speech="">
        </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

What you're looking for is `<div class="left">` .. look at the CSS:

```
.search:hover .bottom, .search:hover .left, .search:hover .right {
    background-color: #33b5e5;
}
```

This is what's creating the little blue line on the left side..

I take back what I said about pseudo elements because they will not work with inputs... You should use a wrapper do achieve this correctly..

Comment: I tried the :before way and it didn't seem to work :/. It seems I will have to go with adding another element to the left of of it.

Comment: Any reason you happened to remove the :before way?

Comment: I'm not using a <input> element, my question would be with <ul> elements as stated^^. The pseudo elements still don't seem to work.

Comment: @IgnianSoft: Did you remember to add a `content` to the pseudo-element? That one trips me up a lot.

Comment: @user1618143 yeah, that was exactly the problem I had, I've decided to give the other answerer the accepted response as he kept the pseudo elements and explained his reasoning quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using a wrapper around the input element.

Suppose that you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <input type="text" value="Search...">
</div>
```

Apply the following CSS:

```css
.input-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
.input-wrap input {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    border: none;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rLCHa/

In this construction, the outer `.input-wrap` element controls the width of the input field and the bottom border, and the height of the left border (10px in this example).

The input field is positioned absolutely and pinned to the bottom of the parent container, and inherits the width. The input field's height is the default value, but you can control it independently from the height set in the `.input-wrap` element.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to absolutely position a div as the left border.

```
    .box {width:205px; position:relative;}
    .line {width:1px; height:10px; background:#ff0000; position:absolute; left:0; bottom:2px;}
    input {width:180px; background:#fff; color:#000; border:0; border-bottom:1px solid #ff0000; padding:5px 10px; position:absolute; left:1px; bottom:0;}
```

html

```
<div class="box">
<div class="line"></div>
<input type="text" value="Search" />
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wnJYY/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you would need to adjust the bottom attribute for the .line class to get it to work cross browser. IE works fine with bottom:0 but Chrome wants bottom:2px