# CSS - how to style rounded area with a gradient background?

Tags: html, css, background

[image]

I would like to ask you about the advice, how to style with CSS the image-background above, what's the best practice.

I got a layout by my designer and this is a background - there's a gradient from silver color to white (from top to bottom), the same with borders.

Top-left and top-right corners are rounded (it's like 3px).

I am trying to find the most effective way, how to code this thing, but unfortunately still can't find the best approach...

Comment: If you `haven't found the best approach` what approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place I like to go for CSS3 styling is [CSS3Please](http://css3please.com).  They use classes like:

```css
.box_round {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
     -moz-border-radius: 3px; /* FF1-3.6 */
          border-radius: 3px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */

  /* useful if you don't want a bg color from leaking outside the border: */
  -moz-background-clip: padding; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box;
}

.box_gradient {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6 */
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* IE10 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999);
}
```

---

Based on your gradient border question in the comments, you could instead use box-shadow to simulate a border:

```css
.box_shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ffffff; /* Saf3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ffffff; /* FF3.5 - 3.6 */
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ffffff; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, FF4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

Comment: this looks really good, and work as well, thanks! But just one question - would be possible to add left and right border to the gradient and on these borders use gradient as well?

Comment: [CSS3 Gradient Borders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2717127/682480) would be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using css on your element:

```
.gradient-bg {
   /* fallback/image non-cover color */
   background-color: /*start color*/; 

   /* fallback image */
   background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png); 

  /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(/*start color*/), to(/*end color*/));

  /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, /*start color*/, /*end color*/); 

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, /*start color*/, /*end color*/);

  /* IE 10+ */
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, /*start color*/, /*end color*/);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, /*start color*/, /*end color*/);

  -moz-border-radius-topleft: /*pixel radius*/;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:/*pixel radius*/;

  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: /*pixel radius*/;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: /*pixel radius*/;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the border-radius rule. You can learn about it at the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius).

To see an example of its use, see http://jsbin.com/aresif/edit#html,live.
Feel free to play around with it.

```
div.someClassName {
   background-image: url("YourImageGoesHere.jpg");
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

**Slight optimization**

That image appears to be a simple vertical-gradient. There is no sense having it be as wide as it is, since in CSS, you can repeat a background-image with the background-repeat rule. You can read about it at the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-repeat). I would first change that image into a 1px wide image. This will make your page load slightly quicker since the browser doesn't need to download a larger image.

Comment: Why use an image at all, and not the various gradient CSS3 tags?