# How to create this CSS border

Tags: css

Hi guys i'm trying to create [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/804/16848527.png/#)(image) css border around a div, but having trouble.

I have created the border but cannot get the border to be smooth. 
here is my code

```
border-left: 5px solid #036;
border-right: 5px solid #036;
border-top: 10px solid #036;
border-bottom: 5px solid #036;
```

Comment: what you mean by "smooth"? http://border-radius.com/

Comment: @deathApril: I think he means the gradient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Gradient Borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle Up, You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/wKFtx/4/).

Hope it help.

EDIT:

Html:

```
<div class="a">
    <span class="abs">Title here?</span>
    <div class="b">
        Hello.                
    </div>
</div>​
```

Css:

```
div.a {
    border-top: 10px solid #333;
    border-left: 5px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
    border-right: 5px solid #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
div.b {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 180px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.abs {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You should really post your code here as well. If jsfiddle goes down, your post is useless.

Comment: You might want to check your fiddle in chrome. There seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can attain such a setup using new CSS3 facilities, namely border-radius and gradient form of background image. You can find information about those all around the internet, for example [background gradient](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-understanding-css3-gradients/) and [border radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

Below is example, it will not work in all browsers, and is not exactly what you want, but it should be enough to give you the basic idea:

The html structure could look like this:

```
<div id="big_div">
    Search for a hotel
    <div id="small_white_div">
    Some other content
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding css would be:

```
#big_div {height:450px;width:250px;border-radius: 5px;background-color:red;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(33,51,140) 5%, rgb(125,187,209) 51%,
rgb(33,51,140) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(33,51,140) 5%, rgb(125,187,209) 51%,
rgb(33,51,140) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(33,51,140) 5%, rgb(125,187,209)    
51%, rgb(33,51,140) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(33,51,140) 5%, rgb(125,187,209)
51%, rgb(33,51,140) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(33,51,140) 5%, rgb(125,187,209) 51%, 
rgb(33,51,140) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.05, rgb(33,51,140)),
color-stop(0.51, rgb(125,187,209)),
color-stop(1, rgb(33,51,140))
);}
#small_white_div {height:400px;width:220px;margin:auto;border-radius:5px;
background-color:white;margin-top:20px;}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's done with background image.

Comment: You can do that via css, not only with background image.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for border-radius to get the rounded corners. Try out something like this:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
```

Note this is CSS3 and will not work in older versions of IE