# Border Opacity Gradual

Tags: css, opacity

Is there a way that I can have the border of a div to blend into the page? So I mean start with opacity one, and blend to opacity 0 through css?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Gradient Borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NkQgt/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `box-shadow` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow