# Html Division border animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been learning css & jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#box
{
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:red;
 height: 80px;
 width: 180px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box">Demo Box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what i am trying to achieve is the border color should appear from left top and flow to create a box border around the division. it seems impossible just want to know expert guidance if this could be done.

*Edit MobyD thanks " like a tron bike "

Comment: it's not very clear what you're asking for. what do you mean by "flow"?

Comment: can be done. but not in a straight forward manner.

Comment: What you want to do? what you have tried??

Comment: by 'flow' you mean gradient? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Comment: I think he means he wants it to go around the div like a tron car.

Comment: You want to animate creating a border from lop-left to top-right, to bottom-right, etc until you end at top-left again and the border is complete? That is very hard to do... You could add lots of small elements around the demo box and change their background one by one to fake this animation... (although I would not recommend this)

Comment: @DavidHedlund first learn how to post question:- http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: it may help you see this  http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: MobyD thanks a lot thatz what i mean

Comment: Veger thanks i guess canvas is the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want an animation around the box, it could be arranged by animating a sequence of lines, each animation triggering the next, as it finishes.

```
addLine1();
line1.animate({ width: width-of-box }, duration, function() {
   addLine2();
   line2.animate({ height: height-of-box }, duration, ... );
});
```

Each line would have to be positioned at its appropriate corner.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LfULS/)

A neater recursive solution could probably be built, but it's something along these lines that you'd have to go with. The border property itself cannot be animated in this manner.

Comment: Works great! Can this animation be looped? I have a working demo here: http://tron.syntheticmedia.net

Comment: @Paul: [Quick fix](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXEB3/). Added color parameter and a callback upon completing the entire animation, so that the animation could be successively called for two different colors. Could be neater, could definitely clean up after itself. If that's the kind of animation you want. If you just want it to reset and start over, you could simply put the entire thing in a function, and make sure you call `$('.line').remove()` at the top.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Cool! That's a good option as well. I'll try your advice on looping. I'm a bit confused though. Put the entire Javascript in a function and then call $('.line').remove() at the top?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want a gradient border or what do you mean by flow?

Yes it can be done.

Example 2px gradient border:

Simply create a div positioned relative which has a gradient background in your colors
Then create a child div positioned absolutely in there with a widht and height slightly smaller
and you're ready.

see http://jsfiddle.net/njL3H/

Comment: He wants the border to animate around the div like a tron car. Not that the border would be gradient