# Making three columns on a webpage out of text

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to make a webpage with three columns. Two of the columns will be the same width and the other will be a little bigger. I also want to create a gradient border around each column.

So far my webpage is similar to this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="border">
<div><p>The text here is column 1<p></div>
<div><p>The text here is column 2<p></div>
<div><p>The text here is column 3<p></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to do this in the best way I can possible I have tried to add this code but I cannot control the different widths:

```
div
{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}
```

What is the best way to put these in three columns and with a gradient border around them?

Edit:

I have tried to use this code within one div and my writing separated within the div in paragraph tags using this css:

```
.cols3 {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2px;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;

  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 2px;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000;

  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
  column-rule: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

But the text from one column goes into the other when I try to change the column gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to play around with the column-gap property, and/or mess with the overall width of the div you put the cols in.

For the gradient border, I would think you would just do a normal border property on the surrounding div:
[CSS3 Gradient Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the content in one div and apply the `column` property to that: http://jsfiddle.net/zgJph/

html:

```
<div class="col3">
    <p>Some text<p>
    <p>Some text<p>
    <p>Some text<p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.col3{
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 20px;
 column-rule: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks how would I make the third column bigger than the first two and also add a gradient border around all the columns?