# Creating a gradient border with the same width around each column in CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to create a gradient border around the text within my page, I have four columns and I need the border to go around the outside and inside of the columns and be the same width.

For example I have added an image:

[image]

The border needs to be the same as above.

This is the HTML I am using below, the problem so far is that where the columns join the borders are adding both borders to it and `border-left:none;` does not work. I also need to know if this is the best way to do this, and other ways.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.border{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-top: 20px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #FF0000;
    <!--margin: 40px auto;-->
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#000), to(#FF0000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #FF0000);
    background-image:
        -moz-linear-gradient(#808, #FF0000),
        -moz-linear-gradient(#000, #FF0000)
    ;
    background-image:
        -o-linear-gradient(#000, #FF0000),
        -o-linear-gradient(#000, #FF0000)
    ;
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(#000, #FF0000),
        linear-gradient(#000, #FF0000)
    ;
    -moz-background-size:17px 100%;
    background-size:20px 100%;
    background-position:0 0, 100% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

#primary {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#secondary {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

#third {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="primary" class="border">
        <p>Column information</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="border">
        <p >Column information</p>
    </div>

    <div id="secondary" class="border">
        <p >Column information</p>
    </div>

     <div id="third" class="border">
        <p >Column information</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include your current html?  Are those "columns" part of a `<table>`, `div`s, etc.?

Comment: probably a duplicate to: [CSS3 Gradient Borders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2717127/1960455)

Comment: @JamesMontagne I have included the current html I am using. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradient borders or not (yet) widely supported. The easy solution here would be to add a wrapper div with the gradient, and give each column div a background color to mask the background of the wrapper. Something like this:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='col'>...</div>
    <div class='col'>...</div>
    <div class='col'>...</div>
    <div class='col'>...</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.wrapper {
    float: left; /* no need to be wider then the content */
    overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0; /* no padding left / bottom, the margin left on the cols takes care of that */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3232 0%,#000000 100%); /* don't forget to add prefixes here */
}
.col {
    width: 150px; /* just some width, any number will do */
    float: left; /* make them appear as columns */
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px; /* same margin as the padding on the wrapper, but only left/bottom */
    background-color: #fff; /* a color to mask the gradient */
    padding: 5px;
}
```

To see a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/6vDmH/