# CSS3 style issue

Tags: html, css

I have created a tag but have white background after the arrow on the right side

```
.tags {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 0;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eR8Ye/5/

how can I remove the white background on the right side of the tag? the background of this tag is a gradient style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this.

http://jsfiddle.net/eR8Ye/4/

1. Remove the right-hand padding from the parent
2. Remove the background color from the `::after`
3. Position the `::after` outside the parent, to the right (use a negative value).

Comment: I would think so too, but the problem here is the gradient in the button(which isn't in the fiddle, just in the question). So what you need in addition to your answer is having a border with a gradient.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that before...  I don't think you can do gradients on border colors.  Instead, you can invert your triangle, using it as a mask instead (make the currently transparent parts the same as the background color, and the currently colored portion transparent)

Comment: Note: you can still put the padding-right on the parent, it would just be only 10px instead of the original 20px (since the ::after border on the right is 10px in size, it fit into the original 20px, so you just need 10 more to have the original look)

Comment: thanks..it shows border of this arrow in Firefox but not in Chrome. how can I remove this border from Firefox also?

Comment: The arrow looks fine in my firefox (v22 on mac).  Might just be that your version doesn't support transparent borders?

Answer (score 2):

Just move arrow to the right and make its `background: transparent`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnilkaBobo/eR8Ye/7/)

Comment: thanks..If it shows border of this arrow in Firefox but not in Chrome. how can I remove this border from Firefox also?

Comment: I don't quite understand. for me it looks same in both browsers

Answer (score 1):

Change the `background` of the `:after` to match the background of its parent. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eR8Ye/2/

There's no way to make it transparent.

Comment: While this does work, you're restricted to instances where you know the background colour of your parent.

Comment: True, but it is a limitation of `:after`. CSS variables could be used, but I wouldn't rely on them now.

Comment: @user270014 There's not any way to use only CSS for this. Neither `background:transparent` or `background:inherit` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [desired result](http://jsfiddle.net/eR8Ye/8/) in 3 steps.

1 - remove the background from the `::after`
2 - change the positioning of the `::after` to -10px
3 - remove 10px of right padding from the `tag` class

**Edit**

With regard to the gradient aspect of your question, it may be worth you updating your Fiddle to show us exactly the issues you are having. [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders) may hold the answer you need.

Comment: Tom's answer doesn't match the padding on his design. Mine does.

Comment: thanks..it shows border of this arrow in Firefox but not in Chrome. how can I remove this border from Firefox also?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've just had a look in Chrome, Firefox and IE and they look identical to me.

Comment: right side of this tag has a border of different color in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Having had a play around with the Fiddle I would say that CSS border-image may be your best bet for what you are trying to achieve. It isn't currently supported in IE though.