# Two color border

Tags: html, css

I know it is possible to have the effect of a double border with one below the other but is it possible using css to have part of the width of a border one color and the rest another color?

Here is an example of an image that I would like to recreate as a border using css only:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean gradient?

Comment: Well not really the look of a gradient, just one color then a hard break into another color.  Can you do that with a gradient and have it only display on the bottom border, not the entire element?

Comment: That image is [290 x 1] black pixels. What on earth do you mean?

Comment: No it's not.  There is blue at the beginning.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. I was confused by the similarity (lack of contrast) between the blue and the black. Perhaps this helps? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**

Seeing that the line in the post is actually a two colored line you can use the border-image property to achieve a similar effect (example showing only the principle but is not adjusted for perfect match):

[image]

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/hwWzX/)**</kbd>

CSS:

```
div {
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:1px;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, from(#07f), to(#000), color-stop(0.3, #07f), color-stop(0.31, #000)) 21 20 30 21;
     /* ... */
}
```

For other browsers:

```
-moz-border-image:
-webkit-border-image:
-o-border-image:
 border-image: /* standard */
```

Note that the gradient parameter varies from browser to browser apparently so this need to be adjusted as well. Demo provided will only work with webkit browsers.

**Old**

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

For this you can use the following CSS:

```
.myClass {
    height:40px;
    width:60px;
    border:5px solid #00a;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #f00 inset;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Here the box.shadow set to inset with no blur acts as the second part of the border. The padding should prevent content from overlapping.

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/DnZJS/)**</kbd>

Comment: No, that is a border under a border.  Look at the example image, it is sharing the same line.

Comment: @fender967 I honestly didn't see any image until after posting. I though it was a black line but I see now what you mean.

Comment: @fender967 there is also the border-image property which can take a gradient, one with f.ex. hard stops.

Comment: @fender967 I updated answer with border-image. The latter values are a bit "harder" to adjust but you can see what you'll get out of it if you'll use it.

Comment: Ah yes, that does the trick as well.  I wonder which would be a better solution.  Unfortunately IE doesn't support border-image, but it is simple in it's implementation.

Comment: @fender967 I also noticed that the gradient parameters must be adjusted for Mozilla and perhaps other browsers. Too young technology unfortunately or it could be a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

I think I figured out one way to do it.  Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/RE4A7/

html

```
<ul>
<li><h3>Mission</h3>
</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul h3 {
font-size:1.2em;
font-family:arial;
border-bottom:1px solid #333;
padding-bottom:10px;
position:relative;
width:250px;
}
ul li {
list-style:none;
}
ul h3:after {
border-bottom:1px solid #ff4800;
bottom:-1px;
left:0px;
content:"";
position:absolute;
width:55px;
}
```