# Css: Menu hover create custom shape background image?(parallelogram shape using css)

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

[image: Navigation MEnu]

I have navigation html and want to add image on hover like this attachment,and it should set properly if menu text is long or short.if normal image is there it could be set but the shape is different so how can i set this?

is there any way to make such shape using any css?

Comment: With CSS you cannot make conditions. use jQuery instead

Comment: He is talking about Hover.. Why should he use jQuery For that. CSS supports hover

Comment: Use the gray gradient as background for your list item and a transparent image with white corners as background for your link item.

Comment: I suggest you read [this][1] so question to learn how to draw a pure css triangle. A parallelogram should be achievable too


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work

Comment: @M1K1O jQuery [isn't the solution to everything](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/219504). It really [is not](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pseudo elements :before and :after

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/hEq2b/1/)**

```
.testClass:hover:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-15px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 30px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent beige transparent;

}
.testClass:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-15px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 15px 0 0;
    border-color: beige transparent transparent transparent;

}
```

Comment: Better solution than mine. I Admit

Comment: just tried it. http://jsfiddle.net/rQgtJ/ it works fine but there is one issue. just hover the menu item. gradient will appear in the middle only not on edges of parallelogram.

Comment: hmmm, I haven't tried adding gradients to borders before, I just found this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6441510/703717, but I'm not sure yet if this will work. Also note that only one of the borders has a color on each of the pseudo elements

Answer (score 0):

use css like

```
#parallelogram { width: 150px; height: 100px; -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); -moz-transform: skew(20deg); -o-transform: skew(20deg); background: red; }
```

check link
http://jsfiddle.net/2G3zf/

Comment: it is not working in IE8.. is it possible  to get hover effect like attached image?

Answer (score -1):

Elaborating on the comment that slash197 gave here is a working fiddle i created earlier for a link button.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xRcXL/994/)

This demonstrates the Hover as well as gradient property in CSS ... This is being applied to a DIV

HTML

```
<div >
<div class="testClass">HOME</div>
<div class="testClass">ABOUT US</div>
<div class="testClass">CONTACT</div>
<div class="testClass">LOGIN</div>
<div class="testClass">SERVICES</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    float:left;   
    background-color:#fff;    

}
.testClass {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 63px;
    zoom: 1;
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: #fff;

}
.testClass:hover {
    background: #eaebea;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eaebea 0%, #d6d7d5 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #eaebea), color-stop(100%, #d6d7d5));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eaebea 0%, #d6d7d5 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eaebea 0%, #d6d7d5 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eaebea 0%, #d6d7d5 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaebea 0%, #d6d7d5 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eaebea', endColorstr='#d6d7d5', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

EDIT: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xRcXL/997/)

Will work on IE9-10