# CSS : Multi color border

Tags: css

[image]
How we can achieve border like this image, using css?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299006/multi-colored-border-repeating-possible-with-css

Answer (score 1):

You can set the border color to transparent

```
border:10px solid transparent;
```

Then you can use border-image property to use an image as border. For example:

```
border-image: url(boder-img.png) 30 round;
-webkit-border-image: url(boder-img.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
-o-border-image: url(boder-img.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
```

According to W3Schools the syntax for border-image is:

```
border-image: source slice width outset repeat|initial|inherit;
```

Learn more about border image here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

```css
p.img-border{
 border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.welovesolo.com/wp-content/uploads/vecteezy/01/1fbahmfyivo.jpg) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(https://www.welovesolo.com/wp-content/uploads/vecteezy/01/1fbahmfyivo.jpg) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(https://www.welovesolo.com/wp-content/uploads/vecteezy/01/1fbahmfyivo.jpg) 30 round;
}
```

```html
<p class="img-border"> Sample paragraph. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an actual design. It could be accomplished with html5 JS but I do not think that is a CSS border.