# Coloring CSS half-circle

Tags: html, css, colors, css-transforms, css-shapes

I made a half-circle, and I want to color it according to the percentage I need. The position of the text doesn't matter for now. What I want is to have 50% of the border colored. Later I will need 70% and 80%. How do I do that?

```css
.info__radius__outline {
  width: 20%;
  height: 6em;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="info__radius__outline">
  <div class="info__radius">
    <p class="info__radius__text">70</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about doing this with css, somebody else might be able to help with that. But have you considered just using images/sprites? Sometimes the simplest solution is best!

Comment: @BenLonsdale I will need the circles to be responsive, so I can't use images

Comment: If you're using bootstrap you could use the img-responsive class, or just do width 100% height auto.... then you have responsive images

Comment: @BenLonsdale I am well aware of that, but I am doing this project in raw html and css

Comment: No worries, it was just a suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a pseudo and rotate it, set rotation via class or js to stick to the value written.

Demo below uses animation to show effect

```css
.info__radius__outline {overflow:hidden;}
.info__radius,
.info__radius:before {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10vw;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  border-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

.info__radius:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width:auto;
  left:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  border-color: gray;
  /* demo */
  animation: rot 5s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes rot {
  80%, to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
.info__radius.p70:before {
  transform: rotate(-54deg);/* remove 30% : do  (180deg / 10) * 3  .*/
  animation:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="info__radius__outline">
  <div class="info__radius">
    <p class="info__radius__text">70</p>
  </div>
</div><div class="info__radius__outline">
  <div class="info__radius p70">
    <p class="info__radius__text">70</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[a few similar examples](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/oxZZLg)

---

---

**About the gradient idea** where you would need 2 gradients and `background-clip` to draw them on 2 differents parts:

- > 1 gradient will be drawn on the center away from the transparent borders
- > the other with the half colored (alike the pseudo) also drawn under the borders area.
- > Gradient can be rotated every 18deg for each 10% .

```css
.info__radius {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10vw;
  border-top-left-radius: 110px;
  border-top-right-radius: 110px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  background:   
    linear-gradient(rgba(209, 109, 91,0.7) ,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) no-repeat center  ,/* can be (white,white) to hide portion of the next gradient*/
    linear-gradient(-54deg, transparent 50%, turquoise 50%) -10px -10px 
   ;
  color:white;
  background-size: auto auto, calc(100% + 20px) calc(200% + 40px);
  background-clip: content-box,border-box;
   
  /*demo */
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px gray, inset 0 0  2px 1px black;
}

.info__radius.p25 {
 line-height:8vw;
  background:   
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7) ,rgba(255,255,255,0.7)) no-repeat center  ,
    linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 49%,black 50%, turquoise 50%) -10px -10px 
   ;
  color:tomato;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-size: auto auto, calc(100% + 20px) calc(200% + 40px);
  background-clip: content-box,border-box;

}

.info__radius {float:left;margin:1em;}
```

```html
<div class="info__radius__outline">
  <div class="info__radius">
    <p class="info__radius__text">70</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info__radius__outline">
  <div class="info__radius p25">
    <p class="info__radius__text">25%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a very good solution so far, but I want to see if it can be done without the animation. If no one answers better than this, I will make this top answer because it solves my problem of quarter-circle

Comment: without animation! you just delete after /*demo*/ and play with transform: rotate(-70deg);

Comment: @siberianl_wolk maybe you did not get notified about Baara Al-Tabaa comment which answers to yours _ *without animation! you just delete after /*demo*/ and play with `transform: rotate(-70deg);`* _ i also updated the snippet (explanation in css comment how to calculate deg/%) and added a second snippet with gradients (i kept the borders, see background-clip to compare to the other answer )

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for CSS3 [`gradients`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp). This will have gradual change between two colors (between gray and red for example). It could be done radially or linearly.

If you want more distinct colors (no blending), I believe you *can* achieve it with gradients and browser specific CSS, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299006/multi-colored-border-repeating-possible-with-css). But if you just want it radially: the [`outline`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) property can achieve this look, if you just change the ratio of wishes between the `border` and `outline`.

If you'd like better answers about css, pictures would be great.

Comment: Thank you. Can give me an example with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

how about this? if you don't mind changing some code.

**[HTML]**

```
<div class="info_radius">70</div>
```

**[CSS]**

```
.info_radius {
    width: 20%;
    height: 6em;
    padding: 2%;
    color: #000;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box, border-box;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%), linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(43,226,147,1) 18%,rgba(226,207,36,1) 35%,rgba(224,83,35,1) 66%,rgba(218,35,224,1) 81%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
    border-radius: 110px 110px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/978zLw2q/

Comment: I need 2 flat colors, not a gradient between them :/ But it's okay, I found another solution

Answer (score 0):

This is just another solution, similar to the first solution from @GCyrillus but with a different approach, using a pseudo element and an `overflow hidden` container. For the animation, a `keyframe` animation has been used:

```css
#radius {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.radius-outline {
    -moz-animation: anim 3s infinite linear alternate;
    -webkit-animation: anim 3s infinite linear alternate;
    animation: anim 3s infinite linear alternate;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    border-left: 10px solid gray;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    transform-origin: right top;
}

.radius-outline,
.radius-outline::after {
    border-bottom: 10px solid gray;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.radius-outline::after {
    border-right: 10px solid gray;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -110px;
    top: -10px;
}

.radius-info {
    color: gray;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 70%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@-moz-keyframes anim {
    to { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    to { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}

@keyframes anim {
    to { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="radius">
  <div class="radius-outline"></div>
  <div class="radius-info">70%</div>
</div>
```