# Border Gradient

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the border of a div have a gradient as seen [here](http://designshack.net/tutorials/introduction-to-css3-part-2-borders), under the 'Gradient' heading.

[image]

I've put the code shown on this site into a jsfiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Df7U8/), but as you can see, it doesn't work.

```
.border_gradient {
    border: 8px solid #000;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors:#897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
    -moz-border-top-colors:  #897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
    -moz-border-left-colors: #897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
    -moz-border-right-colors:#897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to accomplish such a gradient? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works on the latest FireFox but not on the latest Chrome or IE 10.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6441510/1090389

Comment: Your using `-moz-` prefixed properties. These only work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by codehorse, using box shadow inset accomplishes what I'm looking for, and with much less code at that.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

This css declaration will only work under mozilla browser

```
.border_gradient {
    border: 8px solid #000;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: #897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
    -moz-border-top-colors:    #897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
    -moz-border-left-colors:   #897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
    -moz-border-right-colors:  #897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
}
```