# specifically targetting borders for gradient fill

Tags: javascript, html, css

let's say I want to take the right border of my image and make it gradient, starting from my background color and going to transparent.
Is such a thing achievable? In theory I imagine it something like this

```
<div class="faded-edges"></div>

.faded-edges {
   border: 25px rgba(147,147,147,1);
   border-right:  (gradient)
   border-left: (gradient)
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6441510/2126792