# Is there anyway to have multiple colors for a top border in css?

Tags: jquery, css, colors, border

I have a table cell and right now I have:

```
  #myCell
  {
      border-top: 1px solid brown;
  }
```

and I wanted to see if there is anyway to have multiple colors broken up by percentage.  For example, something where the left 1/2 of the top border is brown but the right 1/2 of the top border is green.

Is this possible in css or javascript / jquery.

The only idea I had was to create a table inside my cell with multiple columns (and have each column top-border have a different color) but I wanted to see if there was a more elegant way without having to generate a separate table within each of my table cells.

Comment: yes, you can. google gradient color...

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, just CSS: http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - i dont want to have one color blend into the other incrementally,  i want the first 1/2 of the top solid brown and the second 1/2 of the top solid green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:after` :pseudo-element instead of `border`s and use JavaScript to set the `width`, `height`, `left` and `bottom` properties of the `:after` :pseudo-element according to the `width` of the content.

You could set the `border-width` through the variable `borderWidth`(It is currently set to `3`).

### Example-1: Border with two solid colors around dynamic content

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;
var borderWidth = 3;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "div::after" || r.selectorText == "div:after") {
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth + (borderWidth * 2);
      var h = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetHeight + (borderWidth * 2);
      r.style.width = w + 'px';
      r.style.height = h + 'px';
      r.style.left = -borderWidth + 'px';
      r.style.bottom = -borderWidth + 'px';
      r.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right, brown, brown ' + (w/2) + 'px, green ' + (w/2) + 'px, green ' + w + 'px)';
      // workaround for Chrome so that it doesn't render it with odd borders
      if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1 && borderWidth > 1) {
        r.style.bottom = -borderWidth + 0.5 + 'px';
      }
    }
    if (r.selectorText == "div") {
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth;
      r.style.width = w + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
span {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div><span>This is some dynamic text</span></div>
```

---

### Example-2: Border with more than two solid colors around dynamic content

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;
var borderWidth = 3;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "div::after" || r.selectorText == "div:after") {
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth + (borderWidth * 2);
      var h = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetHeight + (borderWidth * 2);
      r.style.width = w + 'px';
      r.style.height = h + 'px';
      r.style.left = -borderWidth + 'px';
      r.style.bottom = -borderWidth + 'px';
      r.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right, brown, brown ' + (w/4) + 'px, green ' + (w/4) + 'px, green ' + (w/4) * 2 + 'px, cadetblue ' + (w/4) * 2 + 'px, cadetblue ' + (w/4) * 3 + 'px, darkolivegreen ' + (w/4) * 3 + 'px)'
      // workaround for Chrome so that it doesn't render it with odd borders
      if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1 && borderWidth > 1) {
        r.style.bottom = -borderWidth + 0.5 + 'px';
      }
    }
    if (r.selectorText == "div") {
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth;
      r.style.width = w + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
span {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div><span>This is some text which is ofcourse dynamic</span></div>
```

---

### Example-3:  Incrementing border colors around dynamic content

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;
var borderWidth = 3;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "div::after" || r.selectorText == "div:after") {
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth + (borderWidth * 2);
      var h = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetHeight + (borderWidth * 2);
      r.style.width = w + 'px';
      r.style.height = h + 'px';
      r.style.left = -borderWidth + 'px';
      r.style.bottom = -borderWidth + 'px';
      // workaround for Chrome so that it doesn't render it with odd borders
      if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1 && borderWidth > 1) {
        r.style.bottom = -borderWidth + 0.5 + 'px';
      }
    }
    if (r.selectorText == "div") {
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].offsetWidth;
      r.style.width = w + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, brown, green);
}
span {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div><span>This is some text</span></div>
```

---

Comment: thanks but Example 1 has one color blend into the other (as per my question & comment, I don't want that).  In terms of your Example #2, I don't see any border at all when running the code snippet

Comment: @leora - The problem seems to be on Chrome, on Firefox it works fine. Let me see what I can do to make it work on Chrome.

Comment: @leora - The problem has been solved, if you haven't noticed.

Comment: @web-tiki - That is a great idea!

Comment: @web-tiki - But if you need more than two border colors its not possible using `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements alone, right?

Comment: 3 colors is possible with the same markup http://jsfiddle.net/59p8e3ab/1/ but to make more, an extra tag (`span` or `div`) will be needed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting more columns, just add  tags that have different css classes for different colors OR you can write inline css like  (more ugly approach that's not recommended but is simpler).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with border image:

```
-moz-border-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #805d00 0%, #805d00 50%, #38ad20 50%, #38ad20 100%);
-webkit-border-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #805d00 0%,#805d00 50%,#38ad20 50%,#38ad20 100%);
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #805d00 0%,#805d00 50%,#38ad20 50%,#38ad20 100%);
border-image-slice: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

css

```
hr {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:2px;
}
```

html

```
<table>
<tr><td>
    <hr color="brown" /><hr color="green" /><br />
    abc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <hr color="brown" /><hr color="green" /><br />
    123</td></tr>
</table>
```

```css
hr {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>
    <hr color="brown" /><hr color="green" /><br />
    abc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <hr color="brown" /><hr color="green" /><br />
    123</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pseudo element `:before` and `:after` for giving border

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}
div:after {
  background: red;
  left: 0;
}
div:before {
  background: green;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>testing testing testing</div>
```

if you want to give full border

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:after {
  border-width: 4px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-color: red;
  left: 0;
}
div:before {
  border-color: green;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 4px 4px 4px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>testing testing testing</div>
```