# css div gradient shadow/border

Tags: html, css, shadow

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

I couldn't find anything like it, but here is my failed attempt:

```css
#one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #2D8DBD;
  left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -100px;
}
#two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #B22D2D;
  left: -50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<center>
  </br>
  </br>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</center>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5fa820n5/).

I am using bootstrap, so I don't think just making another "gradient" image would be simpler.

Also, I have tried compromising for this: http://designposts.net/fresh-free-css3-and-html5-tutorials/ but my image is circled, and so it turns out as a cut square.

Comment: Use the “spread” value for gradients and use multiple gradients separated by comma. See the [reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Gradient Borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders) - See the second answer on this question!

Comment: While I've brought your code into your question, *where it should be*, regardless of external demonstrations (which are a bonus, but not a replacement), I haven't corrected your HTML; a line-break is `<br />` or `<br>` but *not* `</br>`. And the [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) element is deprecated (HTML 4 and XHTML 1) and should *not* be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fake one, using background gradient and a box-shadow, as well as a css pseudo element to mask the border. Note that if you change the background color of the surrounding content you have to change every instance of `#444`

```css
.outer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px #444 inset;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(250,50,50), rgb(50,150,250));
}
.outer::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -26px;
    top: -26px;
    height: 202px;
    width: 202px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #444;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner {
    position:relative;
    top: -204px;
    left: -3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ee2135, #6279ff);
    padding: 2px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -5px black;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #444;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Styling only past here */
html, body {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #444;
}
body::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.outer {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your request, you need a border on the element that is filled with a gradient effect.

That could be get with a border-image, but then the border-radius wouldn't work.

If your inner background is black solid, that can be achieved setting different backgrounds, and playing with the zone affected by each one (with background-clip and background-origin)

In the snippet, 2 examples, one with radial gradients and the other with linear gradients

**The best about that solution is that the border is still a border. You can set the width, the radius, and so on, the usual way**

```css
.test {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 10px transparent;
}

#test1 {
    background: linear-gradient(black, black), 
        radial-gradient(circle at left top, red 30px, transparent 150px),
      radial-gradient(circle at right top, blue 30px, transparent 150px),
      cyan;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
  background-origin: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
}

#test2 {
    background: linear-gradient(black, black), 
        linear-gradient(to bottom right, red 30px, transparent 150px),
      linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue 30px, transparent 150px),
      cyan;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
  background-origin: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test1"></div>
<div class="test" id="test2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this with a single element, in conjunction to a pseudo element to act as the border. This may have a higher browser compatibility than `border-image`.

**mock up demo**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  background: #222;
}
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: 110%;
  width: 110%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(250, 50, 50, 0.5), rgba(50, 150, 250, 0.5)), linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue 30px, transparent 150px);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 5px #222;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done with just CSS Grid, no JavaScript. Check it out and see if this is what you are looking for

https://codepen.io/dszlauer/pen/RLjwZq?editors=1100#

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="blurBox"></div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <div class="fName">f</div>
        <div class="lName">l</div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  //border: 1px solid white;  
}

.blurBox {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, red, blue);
  filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.inputBox {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  margin: 7px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fName {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.lName {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```