# CSS: split box border color

Tags: css, colors, border

[image]I am trying to build a box, and I want that each line/div to be fully transparent in the middle and opaque at the edges. (In the image, the circled parts should be transparent...) I wrote something like this:

```
.box {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     border-left: solid green;
     border-right: solid green;
     border-top: solid red;
     border-bottom: solid red;
}
```

but, of course, it does not give me the result I want.... I can not figure out any way to fix that "opaque-transparent" problem.. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do?

Comment: by `line/div` do you mean border?

Comment: We really need an image of the desired result.

Comment: @Aaron, yes, the border.

Comment: oh...this sounds like a border gradient. You can't do that with standard borders...you need border-image as I recall,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw your borders via a gradient eventually: `(untill border gradient is avalaible through all major browser ... chrome can do it for ages, FF still not )`

```css
.box {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     padding:3px;
  
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left, red 33.33%, transparent 33.33%, transparent 66.66%, red 66.66%) top left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to left, red 33.33%, transparent 33.33%, transparent 66.66%, red 66.66%) bottom left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, green 33.33%, transparent 33.33%, transparent 66.66%, green 66.66%) top left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, green 33.33%, transparent 33.33%, transparent 66.66%, green 66.66%)top right no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px, 100% 3px, 3px 100%, 3px 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Box-shadow on a known sized box  can do some things too :

```css
.boxbis {
  margin: 3em;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  box-shadow: 70px 70px 0 -60px turquoise, 70px -70px 0 -60px pink, -70px 70px 0 -60px tomato, -70px -70px 0 -60px orange, inset 0 0 0 3px white
}
```

```html
<div class="boxbis">
  <div>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what "to left" means?

Comment: @Nelly it is the direction in which the gradient is to be drawn (starting from right to left )

Comment: @Nelly you may want to look at shadows too if size of the box is known , http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oxzKJp test with gradient and shadow aside   + another old example with transition on last box border http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jdwgG hope that all this gives you ideas and helps to understand how this works

Comment: Can I ask you a couple of questions? For instance, in this line:                                                         <<   linear-gradient(to left, red 33.33%, transparent 33.33%, transparent 66.66%, red 66.66%) top left no-repeat   >>, why did you choose the percentage of colors in this way? Also, I noticed  that one border, can be splitted in 3 parts, but there are 4 colors( red, transparent, transparent and red) mentioned.. ?!

Comment: @nelly the colors and values are split sharp points when values are the same (stop/start), if you remove the values, you have a reguar gradient, play with the pens linked to see how the values effects the gradients :) a gradient needs 2 colors minimum to be effective, but you can add as many you need

Comment: I got it. Thank you! :D