# CSS Button with Gradient Border

Tags: html, css, button

I want to make my button as seen in picture with Silver-ish Border with gradient. I have done everything except the border which I am stuck with it. Below is my current CSS for the button.

[image: This is the image of button I have and need]

```
.button_submit {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0cbbc8), color-stop(1, #008995));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0cbbc8', endColorstr='#008995',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#0cbbc8;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.button_submit:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #008995), color-stop(1, #0cbbc8));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #008995 5%, #0cbbc8 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008995 5%, #0cbbc8 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #008995 5%, #0cbbc8 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #008995 5%, #0cbbc8 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #008995 5%, #0cbbc8 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#008995', endColorstr='#0cbbc8',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#008995;
}
.button_submit:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 Gradient Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders)

Comment: @FredGandt I have checked that before....It's not really what I want..anyway thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `box-shadow` gets it pretty close. You could also play with a `:before` psuedo-element to get the white background.

The key part I added is:

```
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px #333;
```

You'll probably have to play around with it but hopefully its a start.

```css
.button_submit {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px #333;
  
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    background-color:#0cbbc8;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.button_submit:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #008995 5%, #0cbbc8 100%);
    background-color:#008995;
}
.button_submit:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button_submit">
Submit
</button>
```

Comment: My first comment went somewhere...anyway Thank you....This gets as close as what I want....

Answer (score 0):

You can make margin and put another div with the same width and background gradient inside with corresponding z-index .

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button_submit {
    position: relative;
  
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    background-color:#0cbbc8;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid linear-gradient(to bottom, #0cbbc8 5%, #008995 100%);
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.button_submit:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #008995 5%, #0cbbc8 100%);
    background-color:#008995;
}
.button_submit:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button_submit">
Submit
</button>
```