# How to use two colors for border?

Tags: html, css, border

Here is my code:

```
<style>
  .myclass {
    border-right: 15px solid green;
  }
</style>

<div class="myclass">
  Content content content
</div>
```

`myclass` is basically the whole page.

How can I make it so that the right border is 75% `green` and 25% `red`?

Is it possible to use `border` or is there another way?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Comment: Also you can use `::after` or `::before`

Comment: Check https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:before` pseudo class for `25%` red border...adjust the position of red border using position values.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.myclass {
  border-right: 15px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.myclass:before {
  content: "";
  border-right: 15px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  Content content content
</div>
```

---

Another way to use border-gradients

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.myclass {
  border-right: 15px solid;
  height: 100vh;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, green 75%, red 75%) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  Content content content
</div>
```

Comment: Nice trick Bhuwan