# Blur rectangle-shaped div edges?

Tags: css

Is there a way to blur rectangle-shaped div? As you can see on image below, it should be blurred to white color where "X" letters are. Is this possible in CSS?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/gradient-borders)

Comment: @JosephSible but im not looking for border gradient, but for whole div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "x" letters not fixed with the background then you will blur the 'x' letters in css. First call your 'x' letters and past this line in your css { **filter: blur(10px);** }.

Answer (score 1):

I might not use filter: blur() on your div element, as it might blur the contents of whatever inside your div element.

Assuming that "X" letters are just a mark where you would want a white blur to occur, I would suggest a box-shadow method.

```css
.blur {
  background: purple;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  filter: blur(2px);

}
.boxShadow {
  background: purple;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow:  inset 0 0 8px 10px white;

}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
  <p><font color="white">Blur</font></p>
</div>

<div class="boxShadow">
  <p><font color="white"> Box-shadow </font></p>
</div>
```