# How to use gradient values with Theme-ui?

Tags: linear-gradients, theme-ui

I'm using https://theme-ui.com/ to style my components. 
Everything so far as an experience has been splendid but I simply cannot make gradient values work.
I have a button which border on hove should change.
I have the following variant defined:

```
 '&:hover': {
   color: 'lightGraphite',
   borderBottom: '1px solid',
   borderBottomColor: '(linear-gradient(270deg, #FE9A8B 0%, #FD868C 40.85%, #F9748F 73.15%, #F78CA0 100%))'
 }
```

When I open the application the border has gray color and in the dev tools I see `property-invalide-value` or something like that.

How can I use gradient values within theme-ui configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a gradient as the border color in CSS, see here: [Gradient borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/gradient-borders)

This is what the top answer says:

> WebKit now (and Chrome 12 at least) supports gradients as border image:

```css
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00abeb), to(#fff), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #66cc00)) 21 30 30 21 repeat repeat;
```

Prooflink: http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image

I don't think it's a theme UI issue here.