# Element with gradient and border

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I have html like this

```
<div class="bottom-content">
Here goes some content
Here goes some content
Here goes some content
Here goes some content
Here goes some content
Here goes some content
Here goes some content
Here goes some content
Here goes some content 
</div>
```

And css like this

```
.bottom-content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 19px;
  border-top: 1px rgba(red, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 -19px 19px 0 blue !important;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

The problem is that has to be some kind of gradient and border, this way entire element is in opacity

This is how border or bottom gradient should look like

[image]

Comment: this question have been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/gradient-borders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a good job for a blur filter:

```css
.bottom-content {
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.bottom-content::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:lightblue;
  filter:blur(6px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-content">
  Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content
</div>
```

Like below for only border:

```css
.bottom-content {
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.bottom-content::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:8px solid lightblue;
  filter:blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-content">
  Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content
</div>
```

And it also work for only one border:

```css
.bottom-content {
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.bottom-content::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-bottom:8px solid lightblue;
  filter:blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-content">
  Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content Here goes some content
</div>
```

Comment: This has to be just border and not entire content

Comment: @MiomirDancevic you can make it just border: https://jsfiddle.net/fpumd8n3/

Comment: Great can youst be bottom border, make  answer like that that i can accept answer thanks

Comment: This is ok, but not possible on flex display, or maybe you can help me with that also

Comment: @MiomirDancevic show the code you are using, display:flex is irrelevant to my solution and it should work fine

Comment: .bottom-content{ flex: 1 1 auto !important; display:flex;} On this one it is not working

Comment: @MiomirDancevic share a full working code: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @MiomirDancevic you are missing two properties in the parent element