# Why is box shadow fade out not working in this case?

Tags: css

I have the following example :

HTML

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="border-right"></div>
    <div class="bar-base"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$height: 28px;
$padding-top: 2px;
$padding-left: 10px;

.progress {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: $height;
}
  .border-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 30px;
    top: 0px;
    height: $height;
  }
  
  .bar-base {
    position: absolute;
    top: $padding-top;
    bottom: $padding-top;
    left: $padding-left;
    right: $padding-left;
    height: ($height - $padding-top*5);
    border-radius:10px;     
    box-shadow: 
        0 0 0 1px blue,
        0 0 0 2px blue,
        0 0 0 3px blue,
        0 0 0 4px blue,
        0 0 0 5px #FFFFFF40;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#BF0882  10%, white 80%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zlobul/yrm7fLzs/20/

I don't understand why the fade out is working on the div element and not on the shadow box ( blue border) ?

How can I fade out the shadow box too ( blue border from left ( blue ) to the right ( white )  ?

Comment: what do you mean by `fade out`? is it the gradient background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

Glad you could clarify your question. To achieve that you can use techniques listed in this  [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/gradient-borders) or in the [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/) website.

```css
.progress {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 28px;
}

.border-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 28px;
}

.bar-base {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #BF0882 10%, white 80%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}

.bar-base::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: -10px; /* this is important */
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 17px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 10%, white 90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="border-right"></div>
  <div class="bar-base"></div>
</div>
```

#### Old answer

If by "fade" you mean the multiple box-shadows in the `.bar-base` then the code is working correctly. You just can't see it well.

The last shadow in `box-shadow` has the spread only `1px` longer than the others, it's just too hard to see it, also, it is white.

Here's the result if you increase it to `10px` and make it blue.

```css
.progress {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 28px;
}
  .border-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 30px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 28px;
  }
  
  .bar-base {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius:10px;     
    box-shadow: 
        0 0 0 1px blue,
        0 0 0 2px blue,
        0 0 0 3px blue,
        0 0 0 4px blue,
        0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#BF0882  10%, white 80%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="border-right"></div>
    <div class="bar-base"></div>
</div>
```

Converted computed SCSS to CSS.

Comment: No , thats not what I want to achieve . I want the blue box shadow ( border ) to fade out from left to the right ( blue --> white ) , like the content ( red ---> white ) .

Comment: @zlobul I've edited the answer, is it what you wanted now?

Comment: Yes , that is exactly what I need , thanks , so you are achieving it with an before pseudo element , thanks a lot !

Comment: Unfortunately for some unknown reason this solution doesnt work in my project , whatever I do , I'm unable to fade out that line :( . Anyway I will have to research whats the reason for that , thanks a lot !

Comment: If you put it in a jsfiddle I may be able to point out the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , I had to use the ::after element instead of ::before to make it work .