# Border with gradient color in CSS

Tags: css

I am working on my portfolio website but while applying border on my picture I'm facing an issue.

I want the border with gradient of #E70FAA, #00C0FD and I tried this but it's giving a square border and radius wont't apply-

```
`  .right-content {
    text-align: right;
    width: 349px;
    height: 349px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border-radius: 230px;
    background: url('../../a-software-developer-image-in-460-x-460.png'), lightgray 50% / cover      no-repeat;
    border: 9px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E70FAA, #00C0FD) 1;
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }`
```

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Try one of these solutions: [How to do gradient borders in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/how-to-do-gradient-borders-in-css) Worth mentioning that `border-radius` and `border-image` don't get along.